# Input directory is never found

Tags: java

There is probably an obvious solution to my problem, but I'm not very experienced and I've gotten stuck on this point:

My program accepts a directory as input, but the exist check always returns a negative. If I comment out the exist check, I get a null pointer exception.

For example, my start directory would be c:\Start. I enter this when prompted, but it's never found. Is there some syntax for entering directories I don't understand?

```
String startDir;
Choice[] startOptions = new Choice[5];
startDir = ConsoleInput.readLine("Enter directory to start");
String startDirappend = new String (startDir+"/");
File existCheck = new File(startDirappend);
boolean exists = existCheck.exists();

while (exists!=true)
    {
    startDir = ConsoleInput.readLine("Directory not found. Enter directory to start");
    exists = existCheck.exists();
    }

Can startText = new Can(startDirappend+"START.txt");
```

Comment: `c:\Start`, but then you're appending a `"/"`? Can you mismatch slashes like that in Java?

Comment: Instead of hard coding the FIle Separator, better would be if you use "String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");". Moreover, you have to specify the path relative to your class file. How will JVM know where is your C Drive ? Therefore IMHO, **startDir** has to be relative to your Class file, like **"/Start"**

Comment: Good point. I've changed it to "\\" but my original problem remains.

Comment: @GagandeepBali - I think you're right about the start directory being relative to the Class file. I'll have to do some research to figure out how to go about this.

Comment: When you enter the path, are you entering `C:\start`? If so, since this being absolute path you should just check the folder exists in `C:` drive. If you are just entring `start`, then after you create the file object print the absolute path and you will know the path it is looking for.

Comment: Yes I enter c:\start, and I know for certain that the directory exists

Comment: @Dawson: Any difference when you do `new File( "C:\\Start" ).exists()` as against `new File( "C:\\Start\\" ).exists()`. I know this is silly and should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting for a new path inside the loop, but never creating a new File to test with.  Therefore, subsequent calls to `existCheck.exists()` will always return false.

You may want to check what string is passed from `ConsoleInput.readLine`.  It looks like you're not using the core Java libraries to read input, so knowing what you *are* using will help potentially pinpoint the issue.

I don't have the means to check right now, but could the extra '\' you're adding to the end of the path be another potential problem?

Comment: The string I would enter would be c:\Start for example

Comment: Yes, but is that what the call to ConsoleInput.readLine returns? It's more of a validation check than anything, and should help ensure that the library you're using is operating as expected.

Comment: I can't think how to check what is returned by ConsoleInput.readLine.

Comment: `System.out.println(startDir);`